# Telerik MVC Grid not sorting when reloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

My Telerik MVC grid is Ajax bound and I need to ability to apply custom filtering via two checkboxes (in the DIV at the top).  When a checkbox is checked, the parameters would be set and the grid is reloaded.  This is working fine.  During the initial load the data is sorted based on the sorting settings in Telerik, but after I click a checkbox, the data is ordered by record Id and no longer by Priority.  If I then hit F5 the page is reloaded and the data is sorted correct. The sorting might  be a parameter for grid.rebind() or provided in OnDataBinding, but so far I have not found what I am looking for.

QUESTION: How do I specify the sorting order in the OnDataBinding or perhaps in another client event.

Here is my code:

---

```
<div style="float:right;width:600px;text-align:right">
    <span>My Items <%=Html.CheckBox("newItems") %></span>
    <span>Closed Items <%=Html.CheckBox("Inactive") %></span>
</div>

<% Html.Telerik().Grid<IssueModel>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .PrefixUrlParameters(false)
        .Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(o => o.Title);
            col.Bound(o => o.Priority).Width(50).Title("Priority ID");
            col.Bound(o => o.PriorityName).Width(100).Title("Priority");
            col.Bound(o => o.IssueStateName).Width(100).Title("Status");
            col.Bound(o => o.AssignedToName).Width(140).Title("Assigned To");
        })
        .DataBinding(d => d.Ajax().Select("AjaxSelect", "Ticket", new { isNew = false, isInactive = false }))
        .ClientEvents(e => e.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding"))
        .Sortable(s => s
            .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)
            .OrderBy(order =>
                            {
                                order.Add(o => o.Priority);
                                order.Add(o => o.Sequence);
                            })
            )
        .Pageable(p => p.PageSize(15))
        .Filterable()
        .Render();
%>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBinding(e) {
        e.data = { 
            isNew: $("#newItems").is(':checked'), 
            isInactive: $("#Inactive").is(':checked') 
        };
        e.orderBy = "Severity~desc~Ranking~asc";
    }
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
        var param = {
            isNew: $("#newItems").is(':checked'),
            isInactive: $("#Inactive").is(':checked')
        };
        grid.rebind(param);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in case others need the answer.  I used grid.sort() in place of grid.rebind();  The sort method takes a string in the format: column-name dash direction.  Example First

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBinding(e) {
        e.data = { 
            isNew: $("#newItems").is(':checked'), 
            isInactive: $("#Inactive").is(':checked') 
        };
    }
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
        var param = {
            isNew: $("#newItems").is(':checked'),
            isInactive: $("#Inactive").is(':checked')
        };
        grid.sort("Severity-desc~Ranking-asc";);
        //grid.rebind(param);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having that problem too - the solution is obvious and is also working if orderBy is empty (calling grid.sort('');)